# JavaScript ES6 - How to super-construct Object like it can be constructed with "new"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
class Foo extends Object {
    constructor(value) {
        super(value)
    }
}

a = new Object(10);
b = new Foo(10);

console.log(a.valueOf() === b.valueOf()) // false, why?
```

Last time I checked, creating a class that extends another, and doing nothing but calling the super-class' constructor using `this` within the sub-class' constructor affects `this` the same way that the instance of the super class created using `new` is affected.

So why this inconsistency, and is there any work around?

I'm trying to create a class that instantiating returns whatever value was passed into the first argument of its constructor, but with additional properties assigned.

Comment: `Object` constructor does not return the same value. `new Object(10) !== 10`.

Comment: If you were checking equality using `== 10`, then it is coercing the left operand to a primitive, which will have the value you passed it. You can get the same behavior with your custom class if you retain the argument, and return it from a custom `.valueOf` method that you implement for that class.

Comment: ...like this: https://jsfiddle.net/88fo5hfc/1/

Comment: You can't do it directly. `Object` only coerces to object when the NewTarget is undefined or is not the Object constructor itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Object` only coerces to object when the NewTarget is undefined or is not the `Object` constructor itself. Otherwise, it returns an ordinary object which inherits from NewTarget's `.prototype`.

> When `Object` function is called with optional argument *value*, the
>   following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If NewTarget is neither undefined nor the active function, then
>
>    1. Return [OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinarycreatefromconstructor)(NewTarget, `"%ObjectPrototype%"`).
> 2. If *value* is null, undefined or not supplied, return [ObjectCreate](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-objectcreate)(%ObjectPrototype%).
> 3. Return [ToObject](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toobject)(*value*).

In your case, when you instantiate `Foo`, the NewTarget will be `Foo`, so the `this` value will be initialized to `Object.create(Foo.prototype)`, not `new Object(value)`.

So you can't do this directly. But there is the manual approach:

```js
function valueOf(value) {
  var result;
  [Boolean, Number, String, Symbol, Object].some(function(F) {
    try { result = F.prototype.valueOf.call(value); return true; }
    catch(err) { return false }
  });
  return result;
}
class Foo {
  constructor(value) {
    if(Object(value) === value) // Is an object
      return value; /* or maybe `return this`? */
    switch(typeof value) {
        case 'boolean': return Reflect.construct(Boolean, [value], Foo);
        case 'number': return Reflect.construct(Number, [value], Foo);
        case 'string': return Reflect.construct(String, [value], Foo);
        case 'symbol': return Reflect.construct(Symbol, [value], Foo);
    }
    // For undefined and null, let it return `this`
  }
}

console.log(valueOf(new Object(true)) === valueOf(new Foo(true)));
console.log(valueOf(new Object(10)) === valueOf(new Foo(10)));
console.log(valueOf(new Object("ab")) === valueOf(new Foo("ab")));
```

Note you need a custom function to get the appropriate value. That's because, even if `new Foo('10')` returns a number object, it inherits from `Foo.prototype`, which does not include `Number.prototype` in its prototypical chain. But I guess this is intended, otherwise you could directly `return Object(value)`.